# How to truncate value and add plus one from MySQL and display as default value for input?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html, phpmyadmin

I have MySQL database with data like:

```
 id | name
 65 | 2016.C007
 65 | 2016.C006
... | ...
```

I wrote this code to get back the last data:

```
function latestVersion() {

    $con = openLockMySQLdb('labcom', 'versions', 'READ'); 
    $q= mysql_query('SELECT name FROM versions ORDER BY name desc LIMIT 1', $con);
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);

    if ($result)
        echo date("Y").".".$result['name'];
    else
        echo "mistake";
    closeUnlockMySQLdb($con);
}
```

this one result is : 2016.2016.C007 . But i want to write out 2016.C008. Btw i want to add +1 to the last one !!!

Comment: Result is this `2016.2016.C007`. Want this : `2016.C008`. If so, then why you appended `date("Y")`?

Comment: Because i want the first part(before the ".") to be the actual year and the second part came from the query.

Comment: Are the data under `name` column always in this format `year.CXXX`?

Comment: Yes, it's always .

Comment: I mean it takes 3 characters after `C`?

Comment: Yes, it's always like actual year.CXXX (X= numbers).

Comment: okay. what if the `name` column holds value like `2016.C999`?

Comment: That number never will be reached , because the maximum number was 024 . We're using XXX just for backup.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this :

> Are the data under name column always in this format year.CXXX? –
>   1000111
>
> Yes, it's always . – Rickley14

Here's the query:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT('C', LPAD(SUBSTRING(name FROM    LOCATE('.C' ,name) + 2 FOR (LENGTH(name) - LOCATE('.' ,name))) + 1,3,'0')) AS 'name'
FROM versions 
ORDER BY name 
DESC LIMIT 1
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/64041/1)

---

**MORE:** If the number ever reaches or exceeds 3 digits maximum number (i.e. 999) then you need to adopt the following query:

**USE CASE SCENARIO:** For value like `2016.C999` in `name` column:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        'C',
        LPAD(SUBSTRING(name FROM    LOCATE('.C' ,name) + 2 FOR (LENGTH(name) - LOCATE('.' ,name))) + 1,
            IF (
                SUBSTRING(name  FROM LOCATE('.C' ,name) + 2 FOR (LENGTH(name) - LOCATE('.' ,name))) + 1 >= 1000,
                CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING(name  FROM LOCATE('.C' ,name) + 2 FOR (LENGTH(name) - LOCATE('.' ,name))) + 1),3  
            ),
            '0'
        )
    ) AS 'name'
FROM versions 
ORDER BY name 
DESC LIMIT 1;
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO OF IT**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/64043/1)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried the first query but the result was 2016.C1.5 .
Not 2016.C008

Comment: Would you please check this [**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/64041/1). I assumed your selected name column holds value like this `2016.C007`

Comment: I checked it and it works with FIDDLE, but when i copy into my code there is a syntax problem somewhere. 
However if i write like this : CONCAT(\'C\', LPAD(SUBSTRING(name FROM LOCATE(\'.C\' ,name) + 2 FOR (LENGTH(name) - LOCATE(\'.\' ,name))) + 1,3,\'0\')) AS \'name\'
FROM versions 
ORDER BY name 
DESC LIMIT 1', $con);

It"s okay but result is 2016.C1.5

Comment: Would you please run this `SELECT name FROM versions ORDER BY name desc LIMIT 1` and share the output here?

Comment: That was the origin version. The result is : 2016.2016.C007

Comment: Have you shared the result of this `echo date("Y").".".$result['name'];` ? If yes please don't share this. Instead share `echo $result['name'];` I need to know what record is returned as output of the query itself not after manipulating in your `PHP` code.

Comment: Without  echo date("Y").".". the result is : 2016.C007 . With the following query : SELECT name FROM versions ORDER BY name desc LIMIT 1 .

Comment: Then this should work. Please give this a try : ` $q= mysql_query("SELECT CONCAT('C', LPAD(SUBSTRING(name FROM    LOCATE('.C' ,name) + 2 FOR (LENGTH(name) - LOCATE('.' ,name))) + 1,3,'0')) AS 'name' FROM versions ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT 1
", $con);`

Comment: Bad news, It's still not working . The result is: C1.5 .
Maybe that information could help , If i change the "+2" to "+1" the result changes to C002 , or "+3" the result changes to C057.

Comment: If i use your original method and change the part after LOCATE('.' ,name))) + 1,3,'0')) to LOCATE('.' ,name))) + 0,3,'0')) then the result will be C018. It seems we're getting close to the perfect result.

Comment: Can you share a fiddle with all your data of that table. May be I can help then